# Bind IsChecked to boolean of struct wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, ischecked

I have the following `struct`:

```
public struct StreamContainer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public Canvas Canvas { get; set; }
}
```

The following private member:

```
private ObservableCollection <StreamContainer> m_listOfStreams = new ObservableCollection<StreamContainer>();
```

An the following property:

```
public ObservableCollection<StreamContainer> ListOfStreams
{
    get { return m_listOfStreams; }
    set
    {
        m_listOfStreams = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

In my 'Xaml', I have this:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="StreamsMenu" Header="Streams" Foreground="DarkRed"  Focusable="False">
   <MenuItem x:Name="ColorStream" Header="Color" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Foreground="DarkRed" Click="SelectStream_OnClick"/>
   <MenuItem x:Name="GrayStream" Header="Depth" IsCheckable="True" Foreground="DarkRed" Click="SelectStream_OnClick"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Is it possible to bind each of the `MenuItems` `IsChecked` property (`ColorStream` and `GrayStream`) to their matching `IsVisible` property? Meaning, for example, that the `IsChecked` property of the `ColorStream` will be binded to the 'IsVisible' property of first item in the `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Side notes, OC properties should be read-only, the point of it being an observable collection is that it has a CollectionChanged event; sticking it in an INPC property is pointless.  Also, `m_listOfStreams` eew.  Go read the Framework Design guidelines.  Your fellow developers will see that and quietly judge you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that there are always at least two items in the source collection and that the `DataContext` of the parent `Menu` is set to an instance of the class where the `ListOfStreams` property is defined you could do this:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem x:Name="StreamsMenu" Header="Streams" Foreground="DarkRed"  Focusable="False">
        <MenuItem x:Name="ColorStream" Header="Color" IsCheckable="True"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.ListOfStreams[0].IsVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Menu}}" 
                          Foreground="DarkRed" />
        <MenuItem x:Name="GrayStream" Header="Depth" IsCheckable="True" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.ListOfStreams[1].IsVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Menu}}" 
                          Foreground="DarkRed"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```